# I want to disabled onClick event for image inside div onClick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable click event for image using image `id` eg. for `id12` i want to disabled click event . i tried using unbind but it seems it only works if event is binded using j query?

Comment: You can try this, `onclick="return false;"`

Comment: `unbind` should work for any events; additionally try `off` for newer Query versions

Comment: are i have div on click of Div inside click function i want to disable image click event

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#id12").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: my internet is very slow.So i have taken time to correct my mistake

Comment: @Claudio Redi thanks for the edit.You saved me from lot of downvotes

Comment: @Claudio Redi question is to disabled click for image ... indive div on click function

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id12").on('click',function(){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id12").click(function () { return false; });
```

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly this works, why was this downvoted?

Comment: That will also stop the propagation of that event.

Comment: Yep, it works, http://jsfiddle.net/9VgR3/ . Also, the other one doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/u9hmU/

Comment: Please see also [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) In addition, `return false` only works from withing jQuery callbacks, whereas [`preventDefault` is the appropriate DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Comment: @feeela And that's intentional. I really intend to stop the event in all aspects, both from firing on the image itself and from bubbling to other elements of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#id12").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#id12").on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

> Below is pure javascript code. Try this :

```
document.getElementById('id12').setAttribute("onclick", null);
```

Comment: This does _not_ do the same thing as the other answers or what OP is asking for. It'll just remove the onclick attribute (in an ugly way btw, you don't need setAttribute for this!), it will not effect other attached event listeners. The purely DOM method would be using addEventListener and calling stopPropegation from within that (shimming attachEvent for IE, and bubble=false also for IE if you want to stop bubbling, and using event.returnValue=false)